# Can I add a child common project in the root project's dependency management section

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

I am working on an application which got multiple projects.
I am trying add dependency management for one of the common project in the root POM so that I can ensure that all projects uses the same version.

Root/parent pom contain

```
 <groupId>com.citylimited</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-master-project</artifactId>
    <version>12.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>    
    <name>Maven Master Project</name>
     <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- COMPILE Dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.city.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>common-project-jar</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
         </dependencies>
     <dependencyManagement>
```

When I do maven build from my common project it fails as shown below.

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project common-project-jar: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.citylimited:common-project-jar:jar:12.3.2-SNAPSHOT
: Failure to find com.citylimited:common-project-jar:jar:12.3.2-SNAPSHOT in http://server1/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, re
solution will not be reattempted until the update interval of internal-city-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Questions:

- What causing the above issue ?
- Can I add a child common project in the root project's dependency management section and refer in all other child projects?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, since the `dependencyManagement` do not declare an actual dependency, but only says "if someone will ask for it - that's the version". From the error log it seems that you added not only the `dependencyManagement`, but also an actual dependency to the pom - it looks for the common-jar dependency for the common-jar project itself.

Comment: You were correct about dependency management .Its possible and I could find a transitive dependency to itself in my common project. I have excluded that and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot do this. In practice, the jar was not built yet, so it does not exist.
Anyway, declaring the jar as a dependency in any of the child modules with ${project.version} will make sure they all get it (the right version).
Just make sure the jar is built before it's used by others (reactor build order).

I hope this helps.

Comment: We can do this. Pls find JBaruch's comment.